# Coin toss probability.

Tags: probability

Toss a coin until the $n$-th head turns up. Let $Y$ be the number of required tosses, calculate $P(Y\,\text{is even})$.

I am not sure of the solution is correct:

Here's what I have-

P(*Y = n*) = $q^{n-1}p$

Thus $P(Y\,\text{is even})$ = $p\sum q^{2k-1}$ where k = ${1,...,inf}$

So,  $P(Y\,\text{is even})$  = $\frac {pq}{1-q^2}$

Comment: Why would the first toss *need* to be a tail?

Comment: First, what is the probability that $Y$ equals $n+m$, for any $m\in\{0,1,...\}$?

Comment: Have you tried this problem for $n=1$? It should not be difficult. Now try $n= 2$. See how you can generalize now.

Comment: What you have written is only correct for $n=1,$ and you haven finished it off.  $p=q=1/2,$ so what is the value of the sum?  Now, what about $n=2?$

Comment: You should try to be more careful with your notation (it will help you see things more clearly, trust me!). What does $P(Y)$ mean? The probability of a random variable?!

Comment: Sorry about that. It's P(Y = n)

Comment: You are using $n$ to mean two different things: the $n$th head, and the $n$th toss.  Your answer is correct when $n$ (the number of heads) is one.

Answer (score 1):

Assume that m tails happen before tossing the nth head.  Then

P(Y = n) follows NB(n,m,p)

$P(Y=n) = \sum_{i=1}^{\infty} {(n+m-1)\choose n}(\frac{1}{2})^{(m+n)}$

For Y to be the total turns of (n+m) to be even there are two choices

1) both n and m are  even

2) both n and m are odd

$Case 1:P(Y = even) = \sum_{i=0}^{\infty} {(2i+m-1)\choose 2i}(\frac{1}{2})^{(m+2i)} = \frac{1}{2}\left(3^{-m}+1\right)$ where m is even.

$Case 2:\sum_{i=0}^{\infty} {(2i+m)\choose (2i+1)}(\frac{1}{2})^{(m+2i+1)} = \frac{1}{2}\left(1-3^{-m}\right)$ where m is odd.

So if you can let the number of tails be fixed then you can find the probability of Y being even.

For $m = 1, P(Y= even) = \frac{1}{3}$

For $m = 2, P(Y=even) = \frac{5}{9}$

Answer (score 0):

You've got the right answer when $n=1$.  Here's a hint for the $n=2$ case.  Let $Y_1$ be the number of tosses until the first head appears, and let $Y_2$ be the number of tosses *after* the first head until the second head, so that $Y=Y_1+Y_2$.  Now $Y$ is even if and only if $Y_1$ and $Y_2$ are both even or both odd.